# how to change the height of closest column with matching class say abc on click of a button using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

how to change the height of closest column with matching class say abc on click of a button using jquery
this is what i have


this has button on which function is to be applied

height to be changed of this row

What can i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
$(this).closest(".abc").width(20)
})
})
```

Comment: I would suggest the `width()`-method. Also, youre not setting it correctly

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
   $(this).closest(".abc").css("height","150px");
})
```